# How can I prevent a C&C server from accessing my device?

Tags: malware

Let's say I visited a malicious website and it downloaded malware that registered my phone to a C&C server
And after realizing what happened I uninstalled the malware from my device

Will my phone be disconnected from the server? And if not how do I as a normal user with no special software or a decent firewall block the server from accessing the device entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C&C server is not initiating access to your device since this would not work with NAT routers, CG-NAT, firewalls etc. Instead the malware on your phone initiates the connection to the C&C server. If the malware is **fully** removed then the phone will no longer contact the C&C server.

Note that depending on the capabilities of malware just removing the app will not be sufficient to fully remove the malware. In this case a factory reset might be needed. This is more likely if there are known security issues with your phone, which is especially true for older phones which do not get software updates anymore.